# OpenCV read Videos/Images without compression/change

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm currently writing a video segmentation programm in c++ and wanted to read a video frame by frame using opencv. 
Although it seemed to work quite nicely, I noticed some minor changes when reading (and writing) images.
My code to read and write the image is essentially the following (although I usually keep working with the created image Matrices):

```
Videocapture cap = VideoCapture(filename);
int counter = 0;
while(1) {
    Mat tmp;
    cap >> tmp;
    if(tmp.empty()) {
    //cout << "scanned all frames" << endl;
    break;
    }
    //save frames as jpeg
    stringstream filename;
    filename << "original" << counter;
    counter++;
}
```

This codes would work quite fine, but some minor changes in the colors take place, which I would like to eliminate.
This is the source image (zoomed in):
https://picload.org/image/rdddagor/source.png

This is the one which is created (also zoomed in):
https://picload.org/image/rdddagir/opencv.png

Is there a way to keep the original image quality?

Comment: Are you saving images as jpeg?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Stupid me.
Unfortunately that means I have an error somewhere else in my code (but nothing in relationship with this question). 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Miki, I just have to save the images as ".png" (or any other lossless format).